# Javascript - CORRECTLY append new comments without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have asked a question, how to append comments already. I got quite great answer. BUt now i want to know how to append new comments correctly, without refreshing! RIght now I add new comments with just creating new element containing comment and comment user, but they dont appear "from database". Is there any way to append new comments without having to reload whole page, but just the div containing comments, and just adding new comment?
I have this code for now:

```
$(".comments input[name='post']").keydown(function (evt) {
    var keyCode = evt.which?evt.which:evt.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
      var form = this.closest("form");
      var container = form.closest(".comments");
      var olist = $(container).find(".clearfix");
      var input = this;
      $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'comment' letnik_id=letnik_id classes_id=classes_id subject_id=subject_id %}",
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
          $(input).val("");
          $(input).blur();
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data.comment);
          clearfix = $(container).children(".clearfix");
          clearfix.append("<small>"+data.user+"</small>" + "<br>" + data.comment)

        }
      });
    }
  });
```

I have this in the views:

```
def comment(request, letnik_id, classes_id, subject_id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            exam_id = request.POST.get('exam_id')
            exam = get_object_or_404(Exam, id=exam_id)
            comment = request.POST.get('post')
            comment = comment.strip()
            if len(comment) > 0:
                instance = ExamComment(
                    exam=exam,
                    comment=comment,
                    comment_user=request.user)
                instance.save()
                user = request.user.username
                return JsonResponse({'comment': comment, 'user': user})
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

Comment: Add view for comments, and use `$('.comments_block').load('url to view')` ? It first what go to brain.

Comment: what do you mean "add view for comments"?

Comment: add view that render comments for need page, and load them with jquery.

Comment: Something like this https://pastebin.com/E9WNbVUW

Comment: Thanks. SO i just put $('.comments_block').load('url to view') on the success function of ajax?

Comment: Yes, but need clear old data from block(May be).

Comment: tried this, but it doesnt work. Id have to somehow tell the view "get_comments" which model to get comments from. THanks anyway :D

Comment: Also, you can send comment, and in view cond if all ok return template with comments and paste it instead old comments, if not all ok return error and display.

Comment: But wont that cause a reload of the page? If it doesn`t reload page, could you show me how to do it? Help is well apprecciated!!

Comment: Why that couse a reload of the page? If you processed it with JS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143323/discussion-between-mannymann-and-nickita-davidenko).